# Low mouse and keyboard framerate in Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, usb, keyboard, mouse

I have recently added a Fedora 21 partition on my workplace machine, however i'm experiencing the curious issue that my mouse and keyboard "framerates" are incredibly slow. The mouse cursor is enormously laggy and jumps periodically and when i type at normal speed on the keyboard, it drops keypresses. Gnome itself seems to run perfectly fine (the animations when opening/closing windows are completely smooth and not choppy, glxgears runs at >1000fps).

I have done some Google-Fooing but couldn't really find anything. Looked at the howto debug site [1] and couldn't find a problem, although i don't really know what i'm supposed to look for (i'm only just starting out on Linux).

If anybody has pointers on where/how to start hunting this down, it would be greatly appreciated.

[1] https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Xorg_problems

Comment: If the problem is with the controller, then it can be one of several problems. HW faulty, version of the USB on that specific port, how is this usb controller connected inside the system, does it share other resources with other devices, example dvd, etc.

Comment: It works with Windows 7 running on another partition, so i assume it is not a HW issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with one of my USB controllers, plugging the devices in at the other controller resolved the issue.